# What were the Space Shuttle's rules about flying through clouds?

Tags: launch, space-shuttle

I have heard that the tiles on the space shuttle were sensitive to being wet, in that they might be damaged. I recently saw this photo, ported to be of the Space Shuttle launching. It struck me as weird, having flown through clouds, which contain significant amounts of liquid water. What were the flight rules for flying through clouds with the Shuttle?

[image]

Comment: That seems to be the [last launch of the Endeavor](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap110518.html), here's [a video too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YBWaFIs1Rc).

Comment: There's a report here that mentions damage in natural rain (not artificial spray) but not from non-precipitating clouds. That might explain the difference. http://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/pdf/88136main_H-1484.pdf

Comment: AFAIR, we weren't so much worried about the Thermal Protection System getting wet as we were worried about impact damage caused by liquid precipitation.

Comment: It seems like hitting water droplets in a cloud at high speed would cause some impact damage...

Comment: Yeah, the rules below seem designed mostly to avoid lightning hazards and liquid precipitation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the picture I assume you are asking about launch constraints due to clouds (versus cloud rules relating to shuttle entry and landing).  Fortunately there is a nice human readable summary [here](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/kennedy/pdf/531435main_weather-rules-march2011.pdf), and the cloud rules are

> Cumulus Clouds: 
>        Do not launch through cumulus- 
>       type clouds with tops higher than the 41 degree F 
>       temperature level.  Launch may occur through clouds 
>       with tops as cold as 23 degrees F if the cloud is not 
>       producing precipitation, there is a field mill within 2 
>       nautical miles of the cloud, and this field mill and all 
>       field mills within 5 nautical miles of the flight path read 
>       between -100 volts per meter and +500 volts per meter 
>       for the past 15 minutes.
>       - Do not launch through or within 5 nautical miles 
>       of the nearest edge of cumulus-type clouds with tops 
>       higher than the 14 degree F level.
>        - Do not launch through or within 10 nautical miles 
>       of the nearest edge of cumulus clouds with tops higher 
>       than the -4 degrees F level.
>
> Disturbed Weather:   Do not launch if the flight path  is through any
>   non-transparent clouds that extend to  altitudes at or above the 32
>   degrees F level, which are  associated with disturbed weather
>   producing moderate  or greater precipitation, or melting
>   precipitation, within  5 nautical miles of the flight path.
>
> Thick
>   Clouds:   Do not launch if any part of the  planned flight path is
>   through a layer of clouds within  5 nautical miles, is 4,500 feet
>   thick or greater, and the  temperature is between 32 degrees F and -4
>   degrees  F.  Launch may occur if the cloud layer is a cirrus-like 
>   cloud that never has been associated with convective  clouds, is
>   located entirely at temperatures of 5 degrees  F or colder, and shows
>   no evidence of containing water  droplets.
>
> Anvil Cloud:   Do not
>   launch through an attached  or detached anvil cloud if it is within 10
>   nautical miles  of the launch pad if  it is determined to be
>   electrified  and could trigger a lightning strike by flight through 
>   the cloud. Launch can be permitted if the conditions  in the launch
>   criteria directives for Volume-Averaged  Height-Integrated Radar
>   Reflectivity (VAHIRR) are  met. This specifies the distance, time,
>   radar and field  mill measurements required to ensure safe flight. The
>   condition of an anvil cloud must be evaluated for these  criteria when
>   it is within 10 nautical miles of the launch  pad.
>
> Debris Cloud:  Unless VAHIRR launch criteria  directives permit, do not launch if the
>   flight path will  carry the vehicle through a debris cloud which is
>   not  transparent and less than three hours old.  Launch  may not occur
>   within five nautical miles of these debris  clouds unless: 1) for 15
>   minutes preceding launch there  is at least one working field mill
>   within five nautical miles  of the debris cloud; 2) all electric field
>   mill readings are  between -1 kilovolt and + 1 kilovolt per meter
>   within  5 nautical miles of the flight path for the past 15 minutes; 
>   3) weather radar has detected less than 10 dbz of  reflectivity in the
>   debris cloud within 5 nautical miles of  the flight path for 15
>   minutes.
>
> Smoke Plume:   Do not launch if the flight path  will carry
>   the vehicle through any cumulus cloud that  has developed from a smoke
>   plume while the cloud is  attached to the plume, or for the first 60
>   minutes after  the cumulus cloud detaches from the smoke plume.

The Eastern Test Range also had range safety cloud constraints, to wit:

> Direct visual observation of the shuttle is required  through 8,000
>   feet.  This requirement may be satisfied  using optical tracking sites
>   or a forward observer.
>
> – A cloud ceiling of 6,000 feet is permitted
>   for short- duration launch windows if all required range safety 
>   instrumentation systems are functioning.
>
> – A cloud ceiling of 4,000
>   feet is permitted if:
>
> a)  The cloud layers between 4,000 and 8,000 
>   feet are not more than 500 feet thick.
>
> b)  The vehicle can be seen
>   by the Eastern  Range airborne and/or the ground forward  observers
>   through 8,000 feet and they can  communicate with the flight control
>   officer.

There were other weather related constraints at the link provided earlier.

There were weather constraints for the abort landing sites as well.

And, there were many and different weather rules for landing.  Also summarized at the link.